# dynamic input fields validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm working on a web application that includes a feature to add information of vehicles of users, if a user have more than one vehicle he/she can add those details by "add another" like option. i have main form which has 8 fields.

to duplicate the main form i am using using http://tristandenyer.com/demos/dynamic-form.html script. this script does what i want but the thing is i have no idea how to validate the from fields generated by this script.

by clicking "add section" option the script generates a copy of original form, the field names of form goes as "ID2_first_name" (ID2 mean second copy of original form if the form it goes like ID3_first_name)

ex:

form 2

```
<input class="input_fn" type="text" name="ID2_first_name" id="ID2_first_name" value=""> 

<input class="input_ln" type="text" name="ID2_last_name" id="ID2_last_name" value="">
```

form 3

```
<input class="input_fn" type="text" name="ID3_first_name" id="ID3_first_name" value=""> 

<input class="input_ln" type="text" name="ID3_last_name" id="ID3_last_name" value="">
```

....

if a user have 5 vehicles the field of the form named like ID2_first_name.....ID5_first_name.

how can i apply validation rules to these dynamic fields. i am using codeigniter mainly for this.

Comment: help me on this pls

Comment: use only generic name and set it as array, so for example you can have `id="ID3_first_name"` but your name attribute will be only `name="first_name[]"`. this way you will get an array of first names so you can crawl it and validate

Comment: @moped i have tried that way & used ajax for validation. but my that way id & name attribute needs to be same, i can post the code if you can help

Comment: guys i am desperate, really need advice from someone

Comment: can anyone help me here

Comment: when you go through array, you have index and value, so if you find wrong value, you have its index therefore you can identify which input it was..